# расширения стандартных таблиц в wordpress

Tags: mysql, база-данных, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Cтоит ли вносить изменения в структуру таблицы wp_posts, так как по данным добавленным полям будет идти постоянно поиск и данные поля будут присутствовать во всех типах записях. Вариант с использованием wp_post_meta при возможности я не хотел бы рассматривать, так как поле будет не одно и записей крайне много.

Comment: По личному опыту: сайт с 30 000+ записей, у каждой из которых от 7 до 20 мета-полей вполне нормально функционирует на стандартном функционале WP. Имхо, вы зря переживаете. Изменения в структуру таблиц WP вносить нежелательно, можете приобрести проблемы при обновлении CMS

Answer (score 1):

> стоит ли вносить изменения в структуру таблицы wp_posts,

В базу данных вообще без крайней необходимости лучше не лазить.

Для реализации "доп. данных" в ВП есть много разных механизмов - произвольные поля, таксономии, типы контента, форматы и пр.

Comment: К сожалению я это понимаю, но есть опасение, что при большом кол-ве доп полей на смежную таблицу wp_post_meta будет много join-ов, из-за чего mysql отвалится. используется порядка 10-ти доп полей на 3 тыс. записей. Если я не прав, то поправьте меня. Спасбио

Comment: @RomaPankov это семечки для wp. Лично делал магазин на WooCommerce - 14 тыс товаров, куча дополнительных полей на каждый товар. Работало со свистом, такое ощущение было, что и 100 тыс товаров не проблема

Comment: В ВП есть несколько механизмов кеширования. Рекомендую поизучать этот вопрос. Только не про плагины - это не то. Совсем не то. Ещё рекомендую на [ВП.ТВ посмотерь семинары Ковшениных](http://wordpress.tv/?s=kovshenin). Есть несколько очень полезных, в тч и про высоконагруженные проекты.